# Override jQuery UI library dialog focus on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this problem that when I close jQuery UI dialog, the window keeps scrolling to top but I just want my window to stay in the same position. Please have a look at this clip:

https://www.screencast.com/t/lhawhmVpiG

After going through the close function in the library, I notice this is the part of the code that trigger the scrolling (please correct me if I am wrong).

```
if ( !this.opener.filter( ":focusable" ).trigger( "focus" ).length ) {

        // Hiding a focused element doesn't trigger blur in WebKit
        // so in case we have nothing to focus on, explicitly blur the active element
        // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47182
        $.ui.safeBlur( $.ui.safeActiveElement( this.document[ 0 ] ) );
    }
```

If I comment it out, the scrolling stops. But I really do not want to touch the library. Is there a way I can override this code using my own code?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody could help with this please? Thanks

Comment: I couldnt see the clip cause don't have adobe flash in the browser and the connection is 2 slow 2 dwnload it, I'd like to help you, could you include a snippet or a fiddle of the problem. also: what version of UI r u using?

Comment: I use UI 1.12.1. Here is a snippet but I don't think it shows what the problem is. https://www.screencast.com/t/ABTE3VRI0Gt. When I close that pop up, the vertical scroll bar scroll to top.

Comment: uhh, that was not a snippet, that was just an image

Comment: Sorry about that. Thought you want an image. Do you have a computer you can use to view it? I will try to set up a fiddle. Thanks